# Is it possible to have vector as entries in a ftable?

Tags: r

Is it possible to have vector as entries in a ftable? For instance, with input:

```
> mat (or df)
1 0 1
1 1 0
1 1 0
```

I'd like output

```
> ftable(mat)
1 0 1  1 1 0
1      2
```

Comment: If you turn each row into a string, it's just a matter of `table(x)` and parsing values if you are in need of the original ones. :)

Comment: `table(do.call(paste, df))`

Answer (score 0):

```
mat <- matrix(c(1,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,0),nrow = 3)
ftable(apply(mat,1,\(x)paste(x,collapse="")))
```